# Functions for every subclass combination

Tags: c++

I have the following setup:

```
class ComponentBase...

class A : public ComponentBase...

class B : public ComponentBase...

class C : public ComponentBase...

....


class ComponentOwner
{
    public:
          ComponentBase *b;
          ComponentOwner(ComponentBase *newb) : b(newb) {};
          bool couple(ComponentOwner *other)
          { //this in a non-header file, obviously
             return couple(b, other->b);
          };
          ....
}
```

There's overloaded functions for each combination of ComponentBase subclasses, that each return the same type and take the same sort of arguments, like this:

```
bool couple(A, A);
bool couple(A, B);
bool couple(B, A); //should point to couple(A,B) 
....
```

Sadly this doesn't work, since I can't access the type of the ComponentBase pointer without knowing how to cast.

I guess my question is this: How would I go about redirecting two base pointers with unknown type to functions that are there for their type, with as little as possible extra definitions for the subclasses (like enums)?

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

It was proposed for me to add virtual functions, assuming to the ComponentBase.

```
class ComponentBase
{
    public:
        virtual bool couple(ComponentBase *other) = 0;
        .....

}

class A : public ComponentBase
{
    public:
        bool couple(ComponentBase *other)
        {
```

Do I understand the proposal right until here? How would I go about resolving the type of other?

Comment: What should `couple` do?  Does it really need to know the dynamic type?

Comment: @NathanOliver the couple functions use attributes that are unique to the component types to calculate whether or not they are compatible. They are manually written since they differ so much from each other.

Comment: Can you lift the logic into a virtual function?  This would allow you to not need to know the type and then you just need to compare what each function returns to see if the classes are couple-able.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `virtual` and `override`.

Comment: c++ doesn't have native multiple dispatch, you have to implement it yourself (or use library).

Comment: I've added my understanding of your proposal of a virtual function in the question, could you tell me if I got this right?

Comment: Your method can be just virtual not pure virtual i.e.
    virtual bool couple(ComponentBase *other) 
    {
    // behavior if not overloaded.
    return true;
    }

Comment: Look at [Double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: @Jarod42 That seems like a good solution. Thanks.